# How to use SQL Cache Dependency Wtih EF DbContext?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I found this article on using Sql Cache Dependency with Linq2SQL.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=263

is it possible to do this same thing in Entity Framework with DbContext?

I have a multi-database app so each DbContext Instance Connection is different depending on the user. 
But I feel like utilizing this technology would be the best way to invalidate the cache.

any help is appreciated.

Chase

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to refresh context if data change? Do you understand consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, will give you a starting point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx, I tried it and it works fine but I have chosen to use a more custom and light weight approach.

Basically I retrieve the `TraceString` which is nothing but the raw SQL from my `IQueriable<T>` and create a standard `SqlCacheDependency` cache entry.

Answer (score 1):

Your DbContext should live only for single unit of work. In your case for single request processing so there is no reason to involve any database dependency in EF.